# Can we use structure of structure in opencl?

Tags: struct, opencl

I'm using structure as follows.

```
struct domain_data
{
     int *no_h_domains,
     *no_v_domains,
     *domain_hsize,
     *domain_vsize,
     *domain_hstep,
     *domain_vstep;
     struct domain_pixels
     {
          int dom_x, dom_y;
          double sum,sum2;
          int sym;
     } ***pixel;

} domain;
```

But when I try

domain.pixel= (struct domain_pixels ***) malloc(i*sizeof(struct domain_pixels **));

then it gives following errors.

> error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'domain_pixels ***' to 'domain_data::domain_pixels***'

and

> a value of type "domain_pixels ***" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "domain_data::domain_pixels ***"

But the same code is executed perfectly fine in win32 application.

Can anyone tell me, whether I can do this in opencl? if yes then how?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of how this compiles in a normal C/C++ application, so I won't post this as an answer. It seems to be using pointers to other structures, so it won't work in opencl or cuda. Pointers to global memory are not allowed to be passed as or in parameters.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean when you ask if you can do this in OpenCL. "malloc" is not valid in OpenCL C, so you must be asking about your host code, but host code is regular C/C++ and you said this works fine in win32 applications. I think this is just a "C" question and has nothing to do with OpenCL.

Comment: Thanks  Dithermaster ! Even though it is a c question, when I use project type as openCL SDK it gives this error and works fine with win32 application. And I want to send this data to device also ! So can I send this data to device?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is not in the structure of structure, the problem is in the pointers and triple pointers of your struct.

No pointers are allowed to be passed in OpenCL.
Even without that it will never work, since malloc is not allowed in OpenCL.

Please read a guide and a tutorial, before trying to copy-paste a monster C code expecting it to work directly.

Answer (score 0):

It should be doable using OpenCL 2.0 & SVM with Fine-Grain buffers.
Intel is planning to start SVM support with BDW.

Comment: Can you clarify/link what SVM and BDW are in this context please?

Comment: SVM - Shared Virtual Memory
BDW - Broadwell

Answer (score 0):

When I created another OpenCl project and copied same code over there, then that error is removed ! So thanks everyone for their reply!